# React array.splice on state array does not update dom properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have an object like this

```
const obj =  {
      a:'something',
      b:'something else',
      c : [
        {
          a:'something',
          b:'something else',
        },
        {
          a:'something2',
          b:'something else2',
        },
      ]
    }
```

when i call the function to remove one element from the array c like this

```
//where index is 0 for example
const removeItem = index => setObj({...obj,c:obj.c.splice(index,1)})
```

the item gets removed from the array and the page however on the page the element left that i mapped from c have the values of c[0] but if i console.log(obj.c) i get this

```
const obj =  {
      a:'something',
      b:'something else',
      c : [
        {
          a:'something2',
          b:'something else2',
        },
      ]
    }
```

which is actually what i want but it's not reflected on the page..... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is your object passed as either state or props?

Comment: yes i'm passing c[n] as prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Array.splice()` removes items, it mutates the original array, and returns an array of the removed items.

Use another method to remove the item, such as filter, which returns a new array without the item:

```
const removeItem = index => setObj(o => ({ 
  ...o, 
  c: obj.c.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
}))
```

Or clone the array with array spread, and then splice it:

```
const removeItem = index => setObj(o => {
  const c = [...o.c]

  c.splice(index,1)

  return { ...obj, c }
})
```

Comment: i tried but i get the same result,the item gets successfuly removed from the array but on the page the element left is not the one i want, for example if i remove c[0] it gets removed from the array but on the page the one who gets removed is c[1]

Comment: What are you using as the key of the item when rendering it? If you're using the index, react won't know that it needs to re-render the item.

Comment: yes i'm actually using the index as keys....but i don't have anything else to use since when i pass c[n] as prop the properties c:a and c:b they are empty

Comment: problem 1 - The slice method returns the item that you remove, which you assign to `c`.
problem 2 - Using the index as key, react won't re-render items at existing indexes. ie - only added items, or items removed from the end would change.

Comment: You'll to add items with an some kind of a fake `id`.

Comment: i fixed it, i added an id property on c which is id : c[n] and it works now, thanks!